# django .values, joining children with commas

Tags: django, join, orm

Lets say I have the following models:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class GroupMember(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='members')
```

What I would like to do is get a list of values, with the group ID, group name, and a comma separated list of group members.  E.g.:

```
[
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'Group Name', 'members': 'Jill Smith, Jack Peterson, Mike Frank'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Another Group', 'members': 'Another Person, Jack Peterson'},
    ...
]
```

Can this be done using a query on groups, and django's values method?  Something like:

```
group_data = Group.objects.all().values('id', 'name', F('members__first_last_joined_by_comma'))
```

where `'members__first_last_joined_by_comma'` would obviously be something else.

Comment: What db do you use

Comment: I am using postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [StringAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#stringagg) and [Concat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#concat) the [F() expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions)  something in a line of following

```
group_data = Group.objects.all().annotate(
    member_list=StringAgg(
        Concat(F('members__first_name', Value(' '), F('members__last_name'), output_field=CharField()),
        ", ")
).values('id', 'name', 'member_list')
```